# Set default notification preferences, or batch modify them?

Tags: high-sierra, notifications

My Notification Center is a vast wasteland of unwanted alerts. I really don't want to open the Preferences pane and go through Every. Single. App. and click around to change things -- I'll give myself RSI.

Is there any way to:

- Batch modify the settings from the command line, and/or
- Configure default settings for new apps?

I want everything except a few selected apps to basically disappear. This is my work computer, I need to know when I get email or IMs but being notified about an update to some random app I use once every 6 months is a serious productivity killer.